# Android Gradle annotationProcessor not available in parent module

Tags: android, gradle, auto-value

I'm having the following setup:

ProjectA build.gralde:

```
dependencies {
    compile (project(':ProjectB'))
}
```

ProjectB build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.5'
    compile "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.3"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.3"
}
```

And `SomeClass` in ProjectA that is implementing Parcelable

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class SomeClass implements Parcelable {
...
}
```

AutoValue won't generate any Parcelable related methods in AutoValue_SomeClass.

However, if I include auto-value-parcel annotationProcessor directly to ProjectA, the problem is resolved.

ProjectA build.gralde:

```
dependencies {
    compile (project(':projectB'))
    annotationProcessor 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.5'
}
```

Can anyone explain how `auto-value-parcel` annotationProcessor is being excluded from ProjectA?

Comment: What if you put both `annotationProcessor auto-value...` _before_ `annotationProcessor auto-value-parcel`, both in module B?

Comment: no luck, tried pretty much all combinations of ordering these 3 items

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`annotationProcessor` dependencies are not exported to other projects. Also these are not exported with libraries.

AutoValue itself works, because you defined it with a `compile` dependency. This is something you should not do either. So an better dependency setup would look like...

**ProjectB**

```
dependencies {
    provided "com.jakewharton.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:$autoValueVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:$autoValueVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:$autoValueParcelVersion"
}
```

**ProjectA**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':ProjectB')
    provided "com.jakewharton.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:$autoValueVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:$autoValueVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:$autoValueParcelVersion"
}
```

But not having `annotationProcessor` run on all projects would be even better.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation! I've been coming to the same conclusion that annotationProcessor is effective within the scope of it's module only. I tried searching for any documentation on annotationProcessor, but couldn't find anything.

Would you mind sharing any resources/docs on annotationProcessor?