# Room Persistence Library run time exception when calling Rooms inMemoryBuilder method

Tags: java, android, sqlite, orm, android-room

When following the tutorial for setting up the Room persistence library I run in to this error when testing on an Android device.

java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for *PackageName*.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist

I know a similar question has been asked however the issues were due to kotlin gradle issues. [Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154654/room-persistence-lib-implementation-in-kotlingradle-error)

Test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class LocalDatabaseTest {

    private PhotoDao mPhotoDao;
    private AppDatabase mDb;

    @Before
    public void createDb() {
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        mDb = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class).build();
        mPhotoDao = mDb.photoDao();
    }

    @After
    public void closeDb() throws IOException {
    //mDb.close();
}

    @Test
    public void testPreConditions() {
        assertNotNull(mDb);
   }
```

Dao:

```
    @Dao
    public interface PhotoDao {
    @Delete()
    public void delete(Photo... photos);

    @Update
    public void update(Photo ... photos);

    @Insert
    public void insert(Photo ... photos);
    }
```

Database:

```
@Database(entities = {Photo.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
public abstract PhotoDao photoDao();
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for *PackageName*.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
at android.arch.persistence.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:90)
at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:340)
at pics.chooz.choozpics.LocalDatabaseTest.createDb(LocalDatabaseTest.java:40)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "android-apt"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*Package Name*"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 50
        versionName "1.0.32"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    disable "ResourceType"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}
dependencies {

androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$androidVersion"
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'

    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
}
```

Comment: Is it throwing error in testing only? or in developmene also .?

Comment: @Moinkhan throwing the same error for both

Comment: what is the package for AppDatabase?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I changed the 'annotationProcessor' keyword to 'kapt' in my  gradle file. Like so:

```
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

Comment: Same problem here. This fixed it. Going back to a deprecated annotation processor is not optimal though.

Comment: This did not fix it for me - I'm already using annotationProcessor

Comment: `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`  is a must! Even though your build works without adding it, adding it makes the annotation processor behave differently (e.g. not renaming parameters needed for SQL placeholders)

Comment: Don't forget to clean your project afterward.

Comment: I have conflict with Glide when change to kapt. How can i fix it?

Comment: @PhanSinh whats the conflict?

Comment: @dxpelou I have fixed. An Entity missing `@Notnull` annotation in primary key

Answer (score 27):

### Rule of thumb when using Kotlin:

Replace your `annotationProcessor` dependencies with `kapt`. Also, include  `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in your app's `build.gradle`.

Comment: Thanks - as you said `kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$archRoomVersion"` instead of 'annotationProcessor' does the job

Answer (score 12):

Have a look on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065371/android-room-persistences-library-and-kotlin)

The solution is to replace :

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:VERSION"
```

with :

```
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:VERSION"
```

Answer (score 2):

You must add the annotation processor dependency to the module where your AppDatabase is. I assumed that the app would take the depencency from my API library module, where my data model classes are, but apparently this is not the case.

Answer came from this google issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67520422
And this SO answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43918701/1959110

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with

- *gradle 3.2.0-alpha09*
- *koltin 1.2.31*

Due the removal of `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` and other buggy stuff.. I had to downgrade to kotlin 1.1.60 to make it work. Then use:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
}
```

an other option would be to write the DB entities/DAOs and DataBase in Java instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have change scheme but forgot to change version number.

> @Database(entities = {Task1.class, Task2.class}, **version = 2**)

Answer (score -1):

For kotlin

```
 //Room
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
//Room annotation processor
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score -1):

change the annotationProcessor from  annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0' to 
 annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0'

Comment: To turn this into a good answer, you should add some more information. Why does this solve the problem?