# Room persistance AppDatabase_Impl does not exist android

Tags: android, android-room

I have implementd Room persistence for store the notification but it's throw exception with below log,for the `builde`

```
implementation for modules.room_db.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for modules.room_db.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
        at android.arch.persistence.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:92)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:454)
        at modules.room_db.AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(AppDatabase.java:23)
        at MypackageName.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:46)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
```

**Store notification**

```
AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(getApplicationContext()).userDao().insertNotification(notificationDetail);
```

**Gralde**

```
 implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor    'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0'
```

**AppDatabase.java**

```
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notification_room_db";

    public abstract NotificationDao userDao();


    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                            // allow queries on the main thread.
                            // Don't do this on a real app! See PersistenceBasicSample for an example.
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
}
```

**NotificationDao.java**

```
public interface NotificationDao {


    @Query("SELECT * FROM notifications")
    List<NotificationDetail> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE notification_id IN (:userIds)")
    List<NotificationDetail> loadAllByIds(int[] userIds);


    @Insert
    void insertNotification(NotificationDetail... users);


    @Update
    void updateNotification(NotificationDetail notificationDetail);

    @Delete
    void delete(NotificationDetail user);
}
```

**NotificationDetail.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "notifications")
public class NotificationDetail {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int notification_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "message")
    private String message;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "order_id")
    private int order_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_displayed")
    private boolean isSeen;

}
```

I have already search for this,and there is same question for [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44417136/room-persistence-library-run-time-exception-when-calling-rooms-inmemorybuilder-m) i am looking for the answer in android.

Comment: Are you adding the gradle dependencies for Room in another project like another library project?

Comment: @AkshayChordiya no it's main project

Comment: That means you have only one module named "app" which contains the Room gradle dependency. Right?

Comment: @AkshayChordiya yes i have only one module "app"

Comment: In your project did you annotate your NotificationDao.java
 with @Dao? Cause here you have missed it.

Comment: @Debanjan thank you for reply ,i have resolved it before 2-3 days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we are working with `Room persistence` it's good to define proper annotation for each class.

1) Define your `Entity` class with annotation `@Entity` like below

```
@Entity(tableName = "notifications")
public class NotificationDetail {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int notification_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "message")
    private String message;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    private String title;             
}
```

2) Define your Dao interface with `@Dao` annotation,like below

```
@Dao
public interface NotificationDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notifications")
    List<NotificationDetail> getAll();

    @Insert
    void insertNotification(NotificationDetail... users);

    @Update
    void updateNotification(NotificationDetail notificationDetail);

    @Delete
    void delete(NotificationDetail user);
}
```

3) Database class that extends `RoomDatabase` define the `@Database` annotation with all the Entity class,like below

```
@Database(entities = {NotificationDetail.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notification_room_db";

    public abstract NotificationDao userDao();


    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                            // allow queries on the main thread.
                            // Don't do this on a real app! See PersistenceBasicSample for an example.
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
}
```

I have forgot to add @Database annotation in database class

Comment: @Maksim Kniazev post a more details and code that you have used

Comment: Issue was resolved by adding an empty constructor to Entity class